# 마음처럼 what does it mean?

Tags: translation, lyrics

In the phrase 마음처럼 쉬운 게 없고, what does 마음처럼 refer to?
This is followed by 사람들이 점점 미워지고, which I understand to be

> *people slowly grow to become unlikeable*

I know 마음 has many interpretations (mind, heart, feelings etc.)
but neither of the 3 fits the next part.

> Nothing is as easy as the **mind**, people slowly grow to become unlikeable
>   Nothing is as easy as the **heart**, people slowly grow to become unlikeable
>   Nothing is as easy as **feelings**, people slowly grow to become unlikeable

The reason why I think there's more behind this is because it comes from a song,
As I wished by Urban Zakapa

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, "마음처럼" is ungrammartical expression of term "생각한 대로", which means "~ as I thought (on my mind)".

So the term "마음처럼 쉬운 게 없고" can be translated into "There is no easy thing that as I thought (on my mind)".

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Is there also a hidden interpretation for 사람들이 점점 미워지고? Does 사람 here refer generally to people or is there a more implicit reference?

Comment: "마음처럼" is a perfectly grammatical and idiomatic expression: there's nothing ungrammatical about it. (A caveat is that it's not always applicable.  E.g., "생각한 대로 / 마음대로 해봐" is OK, but "마음처럼 해봐" sounds strange.)